# Scala currying with three argument function

Tags: scala, currying

```
    scala> def sum(a:Int)(b:Int) = a+b;
    sum: (a: Int)(b: Int)Int

    scala> var psum = sum(5)_
    psum: Int => Int = $$Lambda$1035/814753967@724c5cbe

    scala> psum(23)
    res0: Int = 28
```

The above snippet works fine but not sure why the below snippet complains.I am assuming that if I put underscore for an argument,I can curry that function

```
    scala> def sum(a:Int)(b:Int)(c:Int) = a + b + c;
    sum: (a: Int)(b: Int)(c: Int)Int

    scala> var psum = sum(5)_(23)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hit on an ambiguity/limitation of the parser.
You can work around it by adding parenthesis

```
val psum = (sum(5)_)(23)
```

Comment: Your answer is incorrect as I demonstrate here: 
```def sum(a:Int)(b:Int)(c:Int) = s"a: $a, b: $b, c: $c"; 
val psum = (sum(5)_)(23); 
psum(50) == "a: 5, b: 23, c: 50"```

Comment: Also, do you realize it only gives the same answer because "+" is commutative right? It has little to do with order or function application.

Comment: yep, it looks wrong now that I take a look at it. Fixing it, thanks!

Comment: I thought the OP still wanted to partially apply the first two params, if that's not the case, @Alexey answer looks spot on.

Answer (score 1):

What you need for this case is `val psum = sum(5)(_: Int)(23)`. `(sum(3)_)(2)` is calculated as follows: `sum(3)_` is the same as `(b: Int) => (c: Int) => sum(3)(b)(c)` and applying it to `2` gives `(c: Int) => sum(3)(2)(c)`.

Comment: Oh, nice observation!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you are looking for partially applied arguments in a function and not for currying. You would have to do it this way:

```
def sum(a:Int,b:Int,c:Int) = a * b + c
  sum: (a: Int, b: Int, c: Int)Int
sum(10, _:Int, 1)
  res1: Int => Int = $$Lambda$1131/1517266286@1981d861
res1 (2)
  res13: Int = 21
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the scala syntax. You can achieve the same semantics like this:

```
scala> def sum(a:Int)(b:Int)(c:Int) = s"a: $a, b: $b, c: $c"
sum: (a: Int)(b: Int)(c: Int)String

scala> def flip[A,B,C](f:A => B => C): B => A => C  = b => a => f(a)(b)
flip: [A, B, C](f: A => (B => C))B => (A => C)

scala> flip(sum(5))(23)
res1: Int => String = <function1>

scala> res1(50)
res2: String = a: 5, b: 50, c: 23
```

Basically, `flip` switches the order of binary functions, so we can use it make the middle argument `b` be the last argument of `flip(sum(5))`.

(*) I took the liberty to make sum give as back a String, which abstracts out any properties that are not relevant to the order functions application, which I interpret as being the core of your question.